# ¿Encontrar Strings iguales de un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo un Array de tres colores, Rojo, Azul y Verde, con un while añado 10 colores aleatorios a un ArrayList. Necesito encontrar todos los colores "Rojo","Azul"y"Verde" del ArrayList, y luego añadir todos los colores "Rojo" encontrados a un array donde solo se almacenarán colores "Rojo", igual con los otros Strings. ¿Cómo lo hago? Gracias de antemano.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] colores = {"Rojo","Azul","Verde"};

    ArrayList<String> listaColores = new ArrayList<>();

    int numeroColores = 0;        
    while(numeroColores < 10){

    int random = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
    String color = colores[random];

    listaColores.add(color);

    numeroColores++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo en tu caso crearía una función que reciba tu **ArrayList** como parametro y busque entre esos colores. Para eso, recorro todo el array y voy preguntando por cada posición cual es el color. 
Esta claro, que los arreglos de colores los tendrías q tener creados anteriormente.

```
public void filtrarColores(ArrayList<String> colores){
  for (int i = 0; i < colores.size(); i++) {
    //asumo q los arreglos con colores los tenes creados antes de llamar a esta funcion
    switch (colores.get(i)) {
      case "Rojo":    
        colorRojo.add(colores[i]);
        break;
      case "Azul":    
        colorAzul.add(colores[i]);
        break;
      case "Verde":    
        colorVerde.add(colores[i]);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Lo que no me queda claro es porque quieres un código así, es decir, los arreglos de colores quedarían todos cargados con un mismo tipo de color, la unica funcionalidad q se le puede sacar a eso es hacer un `colorAzul.length()` para saber cuantos azules tenias, pero no hace falta crear un array para eso. Tranquilamente se puede en lugar de agregar el color a un arreglo, se puede mantener una variable q sea `cantidadAzules` e ir sumandole 1 cada vez q se encuentra un azul.

Comment: ten cuidado con poner código que no esta probado, como parámetro del método haces referencia a un  **ArrayList<String>**, y en el switch obtienes el elemento como si fuera un **Array** colores[i]

Comment: @DarthVader tienes toda la razón, ya mismo edito. El código inicial lo había pensado como un array y luego me recordé que el op lo tenia con ArrayList.